What is the electric field inside an inductor?
In a simple LC oscillation a charged particle was kept in the centre of solenoid ie inductor. At t = 0 will it experience any force?  According to me since the particle is in center it won't experience any force because the induced electric field is radial.  But in our worksheet, they have given that the charge will experience some force.
Is my worksheet wrong or i am wrong or do both of us are wrong?

What was the reasoning presented in the worksheet?

it is a mcq question and they have provided only the answer with no explanation or reasoning.

You can find the electric field inside the inductor using Faraday's Law. The magnetic field inside an ideal inductor is uniform, pointing in the direction along the axis of the inductor. The Faraday Equation, $\nabla \times \vec{E} = -\frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t}$ makes it clear that in the case where the B-field points in the same direction everywhere, the induced electric field must be perpendicular. But in the case of an ideal inductor, the system has complete rotational symmetry, meaning that all forces in the cross sectional plane must cancel out at the center. So you are correct that the electron should experience zero force from the induced electric field if it is in the exact center of the solenoid, and will experience zero magnetic force if we assume the electron is at rest at $t = 0$.
